# vscode doesn't recognize extension .cpp.in

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I've been recently learning cmake and I want to use the command `configure_file` to generate `.cpp` file because I need dynamic values created from cmake variables in my source files. However, it seems that VSCode doesn't recognize the extension `.cpp.in`, therefore the editor doesn't show any autosuggestion or highlight. But VSCode still recognizes the extension `.h.in` and shows perfectly autosuggestion and highlight. Can someone suggest a way to make VSCode to recognize the extension `.cpp.in`? Thank a lot :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXtiI.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to associate the extension with the language.

In Settings, search for **Files:Associations**. Select the *Add Item* Button and specify `*.in` as key and `cpp` as value. From now on all  files with the extension `.in` are associated with c++. I don't know if `*.cpp.in` will work, you have to test that on your own.

More Info: [Language Identifiers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers)